# Default document not working in IIS 6

Tags: .net, iis-6, http-status-code-404

I have a very strange problem that I need help with.

If I open a web site, for instance karlstad.luvit.se/luvitportal in one tab in IE it works fine, I'm redirected to the page default.aspx so I can login.

If I open another tab in the same browser window and go to the same url it still works fine. BUT if I log in to the application in one of the tabs and then go back to a tab with the url karlstad.luvit.se/luvitportal and refreshes it I get a 404 error.

The correct behaviour would be that since I am now authenticated I should get redirected to default.aspx, but as a logged in user.

We are using forms authentication and have set default.aspx as the default document for the virtual directory.

I'm thinking that is causing other problems that also occurs on this site.

Help would be greatly appreciated!!

BR
Anna

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your settings. When you're authenticated, the ReturnUrl looks like it's attempting to send you to karstad.luvit.se/luvitportal/luvitportal/default.aspx, which probably doesn't exist.

Comment: That's true, that page does not exist, the one that exists is karstad.luvit.se/luvitportal/default.aspx. Which settings are you talking about?

Comment: @Anna Johansson - The settings in your web.config for `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms ... /></autentication>`

Comment: These are my settings, I think they look as they should? <authentication mode="Forms">
<forms name="lp2004b" loginUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120" path="/" slidingExpiration="true"/>
</authentication>

Comment: @Anna Johansson - you haven't specified a `defaultUrl` to redirect the user. It's possible that you've gotten it stuck in a loop where it's attempting to login, succeeds, redirects to login, sees the successful login, redirects to login, ...

Comment: I changed it, but same thing happens.  <authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms name="lp2004b" loginUrl="default.aspx" defaultUrl="default.aspx" protection="All" timeout="120" path="/" slidingExpiration="true"/>
  </authentication>

Comment: @Anna Johannson - defaultUrl should be set to the destination page that is not the login page. By setting them to the same thing you've only recreated the same problem (assuming that this is really what is going on).

Comment: I don't think that's whats going on. I have the same forms authentication settings on other sites where this problem doesn't exists. The questions is why isn't the default document that is set on the virtual directory working when I am logged in?

Comment: @Anna Johansson - what is the specific url that is giving the 404? is it the same default page that you're using to login with?

Comment: The specific url is http://karlstad.luvit.se/luvitportal. When not logged in this page redirects me to karlstad.luvit.se/luvitportal/default.aspx as it should. But when logged in it doesn't redirect me anywhere. I just gives me a 404. This is what the request looks like in the iislog: 2010-12-08 15:23:48 W3SVC2 10.121.101.31 GET /LuvitPortal/ - 80 - 89.236.33.162 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows;+U;+Windows+NT+6.1;+en-GB;+rv:1.9.2.12)+Gecko/20101026+Firefox/3.6.12 404 3 0 1795 715 31

Comment: @Anna Johansson - that is strange brew. By virtue of the log, the file is not there. That means either a) the file really isn't there (unlikely), or b) the server is not allowed to serve/parse the file. Is there anything in your global.asax file that may be hijacking the request somewhere? Application_BeginRequest maybe?

Comment: No, nothing like that. This is driving me crazy since we have the same setup on other installations were this works fine. I have tried to figure out what's the difference between the installations but no luck so far. :(

Comment: I removed the virtual directory and recreated it with the same settings. Now its working. Very strange. Thanks Joel for taking time to help me.